# is 35 minutes enough time for a legal layover in Brussels airport

Tags: legal, layovers, brussels, short-connections

I have a option of a flight with a 35 minutes stopoff in Brussels does anyone know if it's legal

Comment: Legal in what context? Airline rules/regulations? National law? As it stands, your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends on your flight.

If you're just in transit, then that's fine and legal. However, if you miss your connection, then it depends - if it's on the same ticket, that's the airline's responsibility to rebook you.

If it's a separate ticket, you have two issues. One, if you miss the connection, you lose the second flight. Secondly, if you have luggage, it likely will need to be rebooked - which means you'll have to exit transit.

So then it becomes a matter of whether or not you need a visa to exit into Belgium. This depends on your citizenship, but if you can get one on arrival, or don't need one (eg European citizen), then that's not a problem.

So legal, yes, but a risk - yes too.  35 minutes is pretty tight - it doesn't leave much room for error.

Comment: (+1) Technically, almost nobody can get a visa on arrival in Belgium and it's likely to be extremely long.

Comment: Well by visa on arrival I also meant 'allowed in'. Eg NZ citizens - we don't need a visa, but we get 90 days on arrival.